# Segre Embedding and lines on $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, projective-varieties

Let $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ be the unit sphere over $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that the sphere has 2 rulings by straight lines.

I have learnt the Segre embedding $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})\times \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})$ given by $((x_0:x_1),(y_0:y_1)) \mapsto (x_0y_0:x_0y_1:x_1y_0:x_1y_1):=(X:Y:Z:W)$ which defines the Segre variety $XW=YZ$ and it has exactly two one-parameter families of straight lines, namely by fixing $(x_0:x_1)$ and $(y_0:y_1)$ respectively.

However, I am confused as to how the above problem can be phrased and solved by Segre embedding: homogenizing $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ gives $x^2+y^2+z^2=w^2$ and we can factorize the equation as $(x+iy)(x-iy)=(w-z)(w+z)$. This motivates us to set $X=x+iy, Y=w-z, Z=w+z, W=x-iy$ and hence
$((x_0:x_1),(y_0:y_1)) \mapsto (x_0y_0:x_0y_1:x_1y_0:x_1y_1) = (x+iy, w-z, w+z, x-iy)$. But this looks very messy and doesn't seem easy to solve for the two families of lines.

Just by inspection I can find three families of straight lines:

$l_1: x=1, y=iz,$

$l_2: y=1, x=iz,$

$l_3: z=1,x=iy.$

However, by the above discussion, there should be only two families of straight lines. Can anyone please tell me what did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your mistake is in the sentence “by inspection I can find three FAMILIES of straight lines”. That’s false. Those are not families. Those are just three lines. The last two belong to the same family of lines if you look at the Segre embedding.

Comment: @CraniumClamp, thank you so much for your reply. Is there any way to see that the last two belong to the same family? I tried to write down the explicit isomorphism between the sphere and P^1xP^1 but it looks very messy and it's not at all clear to me how l_2 and l_3 belong to the same family of lines. Thank you so much

Comment: I made a hasty mistake on the above comment: the first two intersect at (1,1,-i) and the last two intersect at (i,1,1) so can’t be in the same family. It is the first and the third line which are in the same family because they don’t intersect, easy to check this!

Comment: @CraniumClamp I get it now, thank you so much for your help!